# setImage using SDWebImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, sdwebimage

I am setting image to UIImageView as below.

```
[pPostImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/p.png"  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loader.png"]];
```

Now what I wanted is to add button and set its image (so that image is not stretched).

For UIButton Image not to stretch, I found I need to use below statement.

```
[myButton setImage:(UIImage *) forState:<#(UIControlState)#>];
```

But how can I write the cached image in setImage?

Comment: SDWebImage contains a [category on `UIButton`](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/UIButton%2BWebCache.h) as well.

Comment: @Fahim Parkar:[myButton setImage:pPostImage.image forState:<#(UIControlState)#>]; set like this

Comment: @TamilKing : nice ugly way :D: P

Comment: @TamilKing : Put your comment as answer... I will accept it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First time only it download image from URL. Twice you called it brings the image from Cache Memory. Because it stores the image with key as your imageUrl. This is the simple way to set image to your button

```
[myButton setImage:pPostImage.image forState:<#(UIControlState)#>];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set the image or background image of an `UIButton` via `SDWebImage`, you should use the following codes:

Import the relevant library:

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIButton+WebCache.h>
```

Then, use this line to ask `SDWebImage` to download the image for `UIButton`:

```
[myButton sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"IMAGE_URL_HERE"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

similar for background image, use `sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:`